# Switch to a specified WiFi network via bash on a Mac

Tags: bash, networking, wifi, osx

I try to connect to a specific WiFi network in a `bash` script on a Mac.

Two things I want to achieve:

1. Connect to the specified network. I have tried `networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 [network_ID]`, and I could see from the top menu bar that the Mac is trying to connect to the network but eventually it failed. I should note that the network is password protected, and the password is stored in the keychain as I don't need to type it in when I join this network manually.
2. Pause the execution of the rest of script until the connection is successfully established.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**1) Connecting Wireless Network**
You want to add your password. Although the **`passkey`** for my WiFi network BSSID was in my keychain, I could only switch to it and successfully login by adding the passkey directly to the command line in clear text. Nothing else worked.

> networksetup -setairportnetwork [en0] [network_BBSSID] **[passkey]**

**2) Pausing script until connected**
You can simply test the error code of the command above (`echo $?`). Be careful as networksetup error codes are not trivials, grepping for "failed" may help:
`networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 mywifi mypass | grep -ic "failed"`

if the result is **0** you should be good. You could also test directly for actual connectivity rather than simply being connecting to the wifi (better option imho) e.g you could check that you can **`ping`** a host on your network or on the internet. 
You should put all this in a **`while :`** loop which will retry the command until the result is 0. Or you can add a **`read`** statement to your command that will pause the script (my understanding of your question).

Last you may want to add a **timeout** to kill networksetup in case no network is being joined after a while: timeout command, part of **gnu coreutils** may come in handy. It can be installed via the brew package manager: **`brew install coreutils`**.

**3) One liner suggestion**
`! gtimeout 10s networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 mywifi mypass >/dev/null && echo 1 || { ping -oq www.apple.com 2>&- >/dev/null && echo "Connected" || read -n1 -r -p "Connection failed. Press any key to continue..." ; } ;`

**`gtimeout`** : gnutls add the **g** prefix by default to its commands to avoid mixing up with existing default utilites of the same name
**`/dev/null, 2>&-`** : avoid printing the outputs and error codes of the various commands
**`read -n 1`** : pausing until key press